# JQL Query for Acceptance Criteria

Tags: jira, jql

in JIRA, I would like to submit a JQL query like

```
Show me all stories in the current sprint that do not have any accepance criteria
```

Any help? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Here is what you are looking for:

```
issuetype = Story AND "Acceptance Criteria" is EMPTY and Sprint in openSprints()
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried that myself already, but it does not work with ou JIRA server. Did it work for you? Would be quite surprising.

I keep getting the error message "Error occurred communicating with the server. Please reload the page and try again." 

If I leave "AND "Acceptance Criteria" is EMPTY" out it works. Kid you not

Comment: yes! That is how i am grabbing data from our custom field acceptance criteria

Comment: I checked it, then I double-checked it and triple-checked it. It does not work in our JIRA environment. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Maybe you need to take a look at what type of custom field it is?